# Hide one wall of 3D MATLAB axis (i.e. hide the projected x axis in z direction)

Tags: matlab, 3d, matlab-figure

I'm relatively new to MATLAB and wonder if someone could help me with 3D plot formatting please.

I'm trying to remove one of the walls / planes of a 3D axis, to create the below effect:

Example Code:

```
figure(); 

plot3(1:1:10, 1:1:10, 1:1:10);
grid on
```

Produces:

[image: MATLAB result]

Whereas, I'd like the following (produced below using image editing - I'm looking for MATLAB code to get this effect):

[image: Result I'd like]

It looks like I can't embed images yet sorry.

Any help welcomed thanks.

EDIT: Thanks for flagging the similar question up, although I don't think this solves my problem: that solution appears to just set the wall color / visibility, whereas I also want to selectively remove the gridlines from the wall too (but leave the grid lines on the floor - as shown in my picture). Is this possible please?

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem sorry - that solution still shows gridlines on all walls. I've edited my question... Please let me know if I've misinterpreted that other question though if you think it is a solution?

Comment: which matlab version are you using?

Comment: I'm using R2017a

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do that by placing a "wall" or a 2d plane that will hide the wall you want to hide, and paint it in white by editing the colormap:

```
surf(peaks); hold on % 3D plot
box on;  % standard black box wireframe
grid on

ax=gca;  % lets get the axes limits
xl=ax.XLim; 
yl=ax.YLim;
zl=ax.ZLim;

% making our 2d plane
[y,z] = meshgrid([yl(1),yl(end)],[zl(1), zl(end)]);
x = xl(end)+zeros(size(z));
c = -inf; % coding it to be at the bottom of the colormap
surf(x,y,z,c)
hold off
colormap([[1,1,1];parula(255)]); % adding white to the first colormap row
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, although it doesn't quite solve my problem I'm afraid. I want to plot content behind this wall, so by using a white plane to hide the gridlines, it will also obscure any content behind it too.

Comment: my answer will solve whatever content you want to plot. I challenge you to try and prove me wrong. There will always be a "wall" behind all your data points where the plot x-axis positive limit is. The property that is responsible to that wall in the axes object is called [`Backdrop`](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-axes-part-3-backdrop)  and I don't believe there is a simple way (documented or undocumented) to edit it without affecting all the other walls. If there is a way it will probably involve a hack like I demonstrated.